# Kentico 12 (MVC) Inline Widget

Tags: kentico

For Portal Engine we have the option to add inline widgets. Is it possible to do the same for MVC version?

I want to have a button widget that I can add in the middle of a text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Kentico 12 MVC Supports creating inline widgets and please go through the following reference URLs

1. https://docs.kentico.com/k12/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets-in-mvc/example-developing-a-widget-in-mvc
2. https://devdavid.nl/dtk/december-2018/creating-an-inline-editor-in-kentico-12

Answer (score 0):

For Kentico 12 MVC, there is no out of the box way to replicate the "Inline widget" functionality.

A suitable alternative would be to extend your inline text editor that you use on your MVC site with an additional plugin or extension to have the functionality integrated in itself - *the implementation depends on which inline text editor you use*

This is however only valid for the editor you use on the **Page** tab, the **Form** tab rich text areas use the CKEditor plugin extended with Web Forms widgets in mind. The CKEditor on the form tab works fine for editor templates and styles, however inline widgets will not work for an MVC site.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MVC Widget Resolver project here - https://github.com/hades200082/Kentico12-MVC-WidgetResolver

It provides an MVC way to parse out inline widgets from rich text and render them how you like. It works in a similar way to how richText fields in Kentico Cloud are handled in MVC - using Display Templates

Disclosure - I built it.